# Angular StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CdkConnectedOverlay -> Overlay]

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, aot

starting the environment with the command ng serve everything works without errors, but doing a test with the command ng serve --aot comes out this error(StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CdkConnectedOverlay -> Overlay]) in my page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYFt5.png)

I put OverlayModule in app.module.ts, but this is not work.

full package.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.0",
     ...
     my package
     ...    
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.3",
    "@ngrx/core": "1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.4.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "color": "3.1.2",
    "convert-layout": "0.8.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.0",
    "echarts": "4.3.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "js-base64": "2.4.9",
    "jsbarcode": "3.9.0",
    "json-typescript-mapper": "1.1.3",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "6.0.2",
    "ngx-echarts": "4.2.1",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
}
```

Comment: Are you using angular material? Can you post your full package.json file?

Comment: Yes. I'm using @angular/cdk.
I laid out full package.json.